# Collecting every guild and members returns "this.member.get" is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have this discord bot and since I'm personally hosting it from my pc with nodejs I wanted to make the bot update the members list on my webapi everytime I boot it back up.

Problem is that Using the code below the console returns an error saying the member.get is not a function.

```
var timestamp=Date.now(), json={timestamp:timestamp, guilds:[]}, count=0;
try{
  client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    json.guilds.push(guild);
    var list = guild.members;
    json.guilds[count].members=[];
    list.forEach(member => json.guilds[count].members.push(member.user.id));
    count++;
  });
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

The error:

```
TypeError: this.members.get is not a function
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Discord.js v12 you need to use the [cache](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache):

So instead of...

```js
guild.members.get();
```

...you have to do this:

```js
guild.members.cache.get();
```